# Ignoring broadcasts to 10.0.0.255 using iptables

Tags: network, firewalls, iptables

I'm trying to drop logging packets that are destined for 10.0.0.255 by using the following rules:

```
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT  -d 10.0.0.255   -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD  -d 10.0.0.255   -j DROP
```

It doesn't seem to work. Packages are still flowing through this rule and the DENY of them are getting logged at a later rule. Do I need to anything special when it comes to the broadcast addr.?

Edit: Here is the full rule I use that isn't working:

```
# 
# Rule 2 (wlan0)
# 
echo "Rule 2 (wlan0)"
# 
# remove local broadcast 
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i wlan0   -d 10.0.0.255   -m state --state NEW  -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o wlan0   -d 10.0.0.255   -m state --state NEW  -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o wlan0   -d 10.0.0.255   -m state --state NEW  -j DROP
```

Comment: What is your netmask? By convention the netmask for a address starting with 10 is 255.0.0.0, so the boardcast address ist 10.255.255.255

Comment: inet addr:10.0.0.4  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

Comment: Which direction are you trying to block? Broadcasts packets *from* your system, or broadcast packets from other systems?

Comment: hi, it's from other systems. I have a rule later that deny all traffic and log the deny. Issue is that I don't want this later rule to log broadcasted packets from other system so the rule above tries to drop them silently early.

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused.  Your starting example lists `-d 10.0.0.255`, but the full rules list `-d 10.0.0.0/24`, which is not the same thing.  Also it is hard to tell whether you are trying to block inbound broadcast packets (so you don't even see them), or trying to prevent them from being forwarded.

Comment: @D.W Sorry, but I might have an error there. I'm trying to both stop packets from the local interface 10.0.0.255 and ignore packets from other external interfaces on same subnet to 10.0.0.255

Comment: @D.W I have edited the rule again how it looks in the generated script. I'm using fwbuilder to generate the script. I'm using an "Address Ranges" object from 10.0.0.255 - 10.0.0.255 in fwbuilder and trying to drop broadcasts in both directions.

Comment: Mess in question leads to mess in answers (or no answer) at all.

Answer (score 3):

A bit dated, but I felt compelled to help expand the discussion/dialog by introducing the idea of blocking broadcast traffic by demonstrating the capabilities of IPTables to filter layer 2 information as well. Specifically, there's  the **-m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast** command line option.

Here is an example iptables ruleset that demonstrates this option as well as its resultant output:

### IPTables: -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

**RESULTS**

```
[nick@sys]$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          PKTTYPE = broadcast 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          PKTTYPE = broadcast 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          PKTTYPE = broadcast 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

While a tangent, there is another interesting option to provide layer-2 filtering based on (source) MAC addresses, which isn't too useful in this case. However, it is interesting if nothing more than to know of its existence. This is the IPTables **-m mac --mac-source**  command line option. Practically-speaking this option is declared to make sense on INPUT and FORWARD chains (and not the OUTPUT chain). The concept would likely be of more interest for an ACCEPT, versus a DROP or REJECT, action. In the following brief example I ACCEPT broadcasts from the default gateway, but block all others. In this example I pretend the MAC address of the default gateway is: 00:F0:10:03:15:42.

### IPTables: -m mac --mac-source

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:F0:10:03:15:42 -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m mac ! --mac-source 00:F0:10:03:15:42 -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

**RESULTS**

```
[nick@sys]$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          MAC 00:F0:10:03:15:42 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          MAC ! 00:F0:10:03:15:42 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.255          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

In this second example I fully realize that the NOT (i.e., '!') notation for the second INPUT rule isn't necessary; however, it is also a neat feature that can be of some use in this question if selective rejection (or acceptance) is desired.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I still see the packets being logged in the default log rule, rather than getting caught by this rule.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very explicit about what you are trying to achieve, what behavior you actually observe, and how that differs from what you are trying to achieve.  However, I'll try to do my best to guess at what your problem might be.

Here's my guess.  You almost certainly need an INPUT rule to block incoming broadcasts.  I would expect your current rulesets to prevent local applications from sending broadcasts, but it will not block incoming broadcast messages sent by other machines.

I hope you understand that these rules are only going to block incoming/outgoing broadcasts over your wireless interface (`wlan0`).  If you want to block all broadcasts, regardless of interface, delete the `-i wlan0`.

I hope you understand that blocking forwarding of broadcast packets makes no sense.  Broadcast packets are, well, broadcast to everyone on the local network.  So if machine X on the local wireless network sends a broadcast packet, then all other machines on the same wireless network *are* going to see the broadcast packet, regardless of what firewall rules you put in place.  The FORWARD rules (and the whole concept of preventing broadcast packets from "flowing through") your machine just doesn't make sense.

P.S. If none of the above work, try deleting `-m state --state NEW`, in case that is messing things up.  Most likely this won't make a difference.  However, I know I'm able to block incoming broadcasts in my ruleset, and my ruleset doesn't try to filter on connection state, so I know it should work if you leave out the `-m state --state NEW`; it *should* still work with that included, but I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Thanks for the help and pointer to the input rule. I will investigate that. Just so it's clear, what I try to achieve is to prevent logging of the packets. I log all packets at the end that gets denied so I wanted to explicit deny them early without logging to prevent this logging.

Comment: FORWARD rule isn't duplicated because -o and -i distinguish direction. There isn't a "to or from" specifier for an interface.

Comment: @Andy, you are quite right!  My apologies.  I've edited my answer to remove my erroneous statement about this.  I apologize for my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

iptables is wonderful when the schema is thoroughly thought out and optimised for the environment, but it requires serious intellectual effort to get right!

I think of it like this:

```
INPUT - to the box
FORWARD - around the box
OUTPUT - from the box
```

You appear to have subnetted Class A 10.* to a Class C 10.0.0.* I assume you want 10.0.0.255 broadcasts on eth0/eth1.

Therefore, to block just broadcasts on 10.0.0.255 to and from wlan0 and prevent them being forwarded:

```
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT   -i wlan0 -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT  -o wlan0 -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
```

To block the forwarding for 10.0.0.255/32 on all interfaces:

```
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.255/32 -j DROP
```

This would still allow it to be used, but won't cross interfaces in any direction.

I would also add a lot more rules to stop spoofing, bogons, selected icmps and igmp and lock down exactly what addresses/ports get forwarded and blocked to/from each combination of interfaces, so that there is no chance of private addresses leaking to the net, or spoofed addresses getting in, or one hacked machine getting into other machines that it shouldn't.

My iptables ruleset is around 25,000 lines, but most of those are geoip rules to decide what countries can send mail at what times, as well as banned users, brute force attackers, known spamhaus offenders etc.

Maybe I'm paranoid, but as a system administrator it is required!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct rule would be:

```
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT  -d 10.0.0.0/24   -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD  -d 10.0.0.0/24   -j DROP
```

I'm not sure why your rule doesn't match broadcast packages, but in other examples I've seen this format.

Also, an alternative way found [here](http://www.calivia.com/blog/mike/block-broadcast-and-multicast-packets-with-iptables-match-extension-pkt-type) blocks packet based on packet type.

Comment: Nope, that'll block non-broadcast packets too.  For instance, it'll block packets destined to 10.0.0.17.

Comment: It seems like you are right...